# VCL TButton using TVirtualImageList is painfully slow

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I am using Embarcadero C++ 10.3.2.

I switched my VCL buttons to use `TVirtualImageList`, and this greatly improved their scaling behavior.

Unfortunately, now the buttons appear on the Form at runtime extremely slowly, one by one. I am guessing this is due to the internal scaling of the icon images, as regular buttons behave normally.

I made the buttons the same size as one of the standard image sizes in the `TVirtualImageList`, but this made little difference. It happens whether the screen is scaled by Windows or not.

Is there any way of speeding this up?

Comment: Obligatory question: did you compile your code with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Considering `TVirtualImageList` is a new feature introduced in 10.3, it could just be buggy and need some fixing in future versions. Did you [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero yet? How many `TVirtualImageList`s are you using on your Form? How many images are you using? Have you tried assigning the `TVirtualImageList`(s) to the buttons at runtime after they have been initialized, instead of assigning them at design-time?

Comment: Optimizations were on. Will try assigning all the buttons at runtime.

Comment: It calls OnPaint and FormResize on each TButton adjustment so if these methods do significant processing then it is slow. Never had that with TSpeedButton with identical code. Thanks for your help.